# find and replace command for whole directoray issue

Tags: c, linux, shell, replace

see i have one jig.c file in that i have statement like

```
mkvFree(jig);
```

Now i have used following command for find and replace

```
find /home/jeegar/jig.c -type f -exec sed -i 's/mkvFree(/mkvFree((void**)&/g' {} \;
```

By this command i want to get output as

```
mkvFree((void**)&jig);
```

But i get output like

```
mkvFree((void**)mkvFree(jig);
```

whats wrong with my command ?

**Edit :**

i have taken this command from https://superuser.com/questions/324428/find-and-replace-command-for-whole-directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the \& character:

```
find /home/jeegar/jig.c -type f -exec \
       sed -i 's/mkvFree(/mkvFree((void**)\&/g' {} \;
```

The `&` character would substitute the whole matched input for the pattern.

Comment: can you say me the all name of such metacharacter ..? which can be create such problem

Comment: [man sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed), search for 'replacement' (or 'special character')

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a metacharacter in the replacement expression, meaning "the whole search string". Quote it and it should work.

Comment: can you say me the all name of such metacharacter ..? which can be create such problem..

Comment: in the replacement, `\``, `&` and newline are special. See http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command